# How can i reverse an equation in java

Tags: java

I got this question during an interview but was not able to do for double digit number.

```
import java.util.Stack;

public class ReverseAnEquation {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 String s="2+3*5";
 reverse(s);
}

private static void reverse(String s) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Stack st=new Stack<>();

    char[] r=s.toCharArray();
    for(char a:r) {
        st.push(a);
    }
    System.out.println("popping values");

    while(!st.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.print(st.pop());
    }

}

}
```

For example:

input: 20+30-45*60

output: 60*45-30+20

Comment: Which is "the question"? What have you tried so far?

Comment: what you looking for is called tokenization

Answer (score 2):

Quite simply, right now you're pushing characters when you really need to be pushing tokens.

Assuming there's no parentheses to worry about, keep a String for adding numbers and only push it when you reach a non-number. While you keep grabbing numbers, append the characters on to the end of that String (well, probably StringBuilder if you want to be efficient...)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use a `Stack` then this should work:

```
private static void reverse(String s) {
    String[] operators = {"\\+", "-", "\\*", "/"};

    for (String op : operators) {
        s = s.replaceAll(op, " " + op + " ");
    }

    String[] splitted = s.split(" ");

    Stack st=new Stack<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < splitted.length; i++) {
        st.push(splitted[i]);
    }

    System.out.println("popping values");

    while(!st.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.print(st.pop());
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s="20+30-45*60";
    reverse(s);
}
```

will print:

```
60*45-30+20
```

**Without** a `Stack` it's even easier:

```
private static void reverse(String s) {
    String[] operators = {"\\+", "-", "\\*", "/"};

    for (String op : operators) {
        s = s.replaceAll(op, " " + op + " ");
    }

    String[] splitted = s.split(" ");

    for (int i = splitted.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        System.out.print(splitted[i]);
    }
}
```